# When the top of a mountain is seen with elevation angle 30 degrees has height of 2.460m, what is the height of the explosion with elevation angle 60?

Tags: trigonometry, circles

Perhaps one may think that the height of the explosion is supposed two times, i.e., 4.920m, compared to the mountain with the elevation angle 30 degrees since the degree magnitude is two times larger. It may refer to the concept that a semicircle has circumference half of a circle. However, based on the solution, to solve that problem is using trigonometry. The length from the bottom to the top of the explosion is three times longer than that of the height of the mountain  Anyone can explain this thing?

[image: For example, in the figure, the height of the explosion from the bottom is not twice than that of the mountain, instead, using trigonometry, the height of the explosion is three times than that of the mountain]

Comment: Draw a diagram of the situation! That will always be the place to start.

Comment: Nice diagram! Why does the diagram state $2.460m$ whereas your title says $15m$?

Comment: @String, I explained in the similar situation but I have edited it

Comment: Ah, now it makes sense!

Answer (score 2):

Using trigonometry, we can see that the smaller triangle has the equation
$$ \frac{2.460m}{d}=\tan(30)$$

where $d$ is the distance from the observer to the mountain in the horizontal direction.

At the same time, the bigger triangle has the equation
$$ \frac{h}{d}=\tan(60)$$

where $h$ is the height of the explosion we are looking for.
Rewriting the equations to isolate $d$ brings us to
$$ d=\frac{2.460m}{\tan(30)}$$
$$ d=\frac{x}{\tan(60)}$$

and thus
$$\frac{2.460m}{\tan(30)}=\frac{x}{\tan(60)}$$ holds.

In other words, the value $x$ is just
$$x=2.460m \cdot \frac{\tan(60)}{\tan(30)}$$

so the increase is not the degree magnitude difference, but the quotient of the tangens.

Computing that value gives us
$$\frac{\tan(60)}{\tan(30)}=\frac{\sin(60)\cos(30)}{\sin(30)\cos(60)}\frac{0.5 \sqrt{3} \cdot 0.5\sqrt{3}}{0.5 \cdot 0.5}=3$$ thus the final value for the height of the explosion is
$$x=2.460m \cdot 3 = 7380$$

EDIT: My reasoning was incorrect, it has to be $\tan(30)$ instead of $\sin(30)$ to get the same $d$!.

Comment: Nice! Just be careful to make sure to state that $\sin$ must be evaluated using degrees, not radians.

Comment: Also be careful not to confuse $d$ with the horizontal leg. Your wording might confuse someone.

Comment: $d$ IS the horizontal lag. But yeah the answer was wrong, it has to be tangens instead of sine!

Comment: You are right about that. We both made the same mistake simultaneously.

Comment: Yeah funny how minds work sometimes :D

Comment: Yes, it is really difficult to share a hypotenuse when they are completely different length :D

Comment: I caught my error too late. People started downvoting - without leaving a comment, which is a bit annoying.

Answer (score 1):

You are quite right that angles are, in essence, a circular measure whereas heights are measured in a straight line, which is quite different. We have:
$$
\tan v=\frac{h}{w}
$$
where $h$ is the height opposite the angle, and $w$ is the shared horizontal leg. Thus two heights compare in the same ratio as the corresponding $\tan$-values. This yields:
$$
\frac{\tan 60^\circ}{\tan 30^\circ}=\frac{\sqrt 3}{\sqrt 3/3}=3
$$
then this is the factor to multiply $2460m$ by:
$$
2460m\cdot 3=7380m
$$